# Confused about scalability

Tags: architecture, scalability

According to this quote, if I design a scalable arquitecture it will scale when required, no matter the technology.

```
Languages, libraries and frameworks don't scale. Architectures do.
```

and according to the [wikipedia scalability page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) scalability is about hardware (nodes and memory).

What does scale mean and when is an application really scalable?

Comment: When the performace of your application increases as close to linerly as possible when hardware is increased.

Comment: I don't know how much stock I'd put into quotes like that. They're too vague and broad to be true (or false). Reality is always more complex.

Answer (score 0):

"Languages, libraries and frameworks don't scale. Architectures do."

This is a true statement. Since,languages,libraries and frameworks should be treated as "instruments" for architecture implementation.

Let me explain in detail,In Good Architectures- components(like languages,frameworks etc) can be replaced or interchanged. for e.g. Many open source project implementations are available in different languages.

In terms of scalability of these architectures, as these architectures are built upon common set of features of languages/frameworks/libraries-these architectures scales well.

Pls note, performance of systems is very different from scalability of system.

Answer (score 0):

Scalability is usually an attribute of Distributed Systems where there is multiple users (e.g. websites) but that is not necessary. Scalability can involve hardware options (e.g. increase server memory or CPU power to handle more users at the same time), but in your case what i think this quote means is that you should use an architecture (Software architecture) to develop your software that is independent of the tools used to build that software (hence the languages, frameworks and libraries). For example develop your software using the layered architecture or other famous software architectures that enable the application to scale.
*NOTE:* this is my personal opinion and it isn't based on any formal or scientific definitions.